# MFC VS2010 Can't Add CDialogEx derived class by wizard

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

In my MFC project I try to create dialog. So in Resource View insert Dialog.
Then double click inside dialog, to get dialog class. MFC Add Class Wizard runs, when I input Class name, and select Base class: CDialogEx. Click Finish button, wizard closes and nothing else happens. None files (cpp, h) is created.

Can You tell me what can be wrong?

As workaround I create manualy files .cpp and .h where derive class from CDialogEx, it is displayed correctly , and I can work with it (messages are handled correctly)
But I have other problems, with Add variable to controls for example.

Comment: Close the solution, delete the temporary `.sdf` and `.aps` files, re-open the solution, wait for intellisense to rebuild, try again.

Comment: There is both, progress and regress. 

Progress, because after click Finish, something is happening, files are created, but they are empty.

Regress because after some time (few seconds) Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to be close. In three tries crash three times 

So I try also Clean and Rebuild solution. which didn't help

Comment: Repair/Reinstall Visual Studio.